# Cant unlock from Ubuntu launcher 14.04

Tags: launcher

Sorry to say i googled for this issue and found lot of solution but not any other is working.
Could you any one guide me how i could unlock items from launcher?

Comment: Right-clicking doesn't work? I mean, right-click *and* select the proper option...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happy to inform you people is that follwoing command helps me to resolve this issue.

```
 sudo apt-get remove zeitgeist zeitgeist-datahub zeitgeist-core
```

Comment: I am glad you fixed your issue, however, this does not answer your question as you did not unlock it from the launcher but removed it from the system. If that was you goal, could you please update your question to reflect the answer?

Comment: i dont know much about the core but my requirement was to be able to unlock from launch bar that i did not able to do. Using the above command  now every thing become normal as before.

Answer (score 5):

If everything is working fine, right-click the item on the Launcher and from the context menu select *Unlock from Launcher*.

[image: IMG:]

Otherwise:

Close Firefox if it is open to free CPU resources, and try to unlock the item from the Launcher again.

Close all open applications and try to unlock the item from the Launcher again.

If this doesn't work, the next thing to try would be to log out and login again followed by rebooting if logout/login doesn't work either.

Comment: no maan this is not working.

Comment: everything is working fine. I have tried removing zeitgeist this too but alas nothing is working.

Comment: Maybe it's one of these bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zeitgeist/+bug/722762 or https://bugs.launchpad.net/zeitgeist/+bug/796194